# get iphone drawing into a browser

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ipad

i need to build a system where our customers can sign a contract on the ipad or galaxy-tab of our employees.

i am a ruby-on-rails webdeveloper so it would be easist thing for me to do it as an onlineapplication.

big big questions is:
my guy says, his ipad has such a great function with the pen, that he can write/sign things.

is it possible to grab this input with a browser? like im making a drawing-canvas, and when the submits the form, the ipad generates it as an image and send it to the server?

otherwise i need to build up a native app. my guy wants to keep his ipad, so i get in trouble while every app needs to be downloaded by the appstore - means i cant develop him a app and only he can get it. right?

Comment: You can deploy apps without going via the AppStore using an Enterprise license. You can deploy without on up to 100 devices on a standard account too, but Enterprise is probably the way you'd want to go. As for the drawing, the finger on the screen is in essence a mouse, so if you have a web component that could draw following a mouse pointer, then the same component should draw following the finger on the screen.

Comment: okay, so i can use the HTML5::Canvas. remember the coordinates he was writing to, send the coordinates to the server and there i need to draw it as PNG with imagemagick or whatever. that saves me from makeing an app for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,
build my own formtastic input

```
**canvas to image** – An input plugin to use a canvas for drawings (mostly autographs). the 
drawing will be submitted to the server

Link to Gist: https://gist.github.com/4678219
```